# Which Versions of Entity Framework are Compatible with Web API 2?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

It seems that Web Api 2 projects ship with Entity Framework 6 as standard. I am not currently lucky enough to be able to use EF6, so have been trying to get this working with an earlier version of EF. Is this going to cause issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no direct relation between them.

If you model your project in a right way, and make a data access and business logic layers, which are separated from your `API` service layer this should work.

You should isolate your service layer from other layers and you'd be fine.

The best way to this is creating `Data Transfer Objects` as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5).

Your web api layer should not be a part of the layers described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-business-logic-layer-cs):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will mark your answer once I have checked it out a little more.